# How can I reverse latency added on an interface from my script which is in Python?

Tags: python

In my script I am using api's from another Python script. I am able to add latency but similar to add_latency there is another function to remove latency which is remove_latency. What I want to do is after add latency to interface I want to remove it when I do a cntrl c and invoke sigint.

```
def url(a, b, c):
        url = f"http://{a}:5000/{c}?ms={b}"
        return url

def main_func(url, endpoint_name):
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code // 100 == 2:
                print('OK')
                return True
        else:
                print(f"ERROR in {endpoint_name}. URL: {url}. Response code: {response.status_code}")
        return False

def add_latency(mbxIP, latency):
        return main_func(url(mbxIP, latency, 'add_latency'), add_latency)

def remove_latency(mbxIP, latency):
        return main_func(url(mbxIP, latency, 'remove_latency'), remove_latency)
```

The above code is which I am using to add and remove latency.
Below is the sighandler:

```
def gracefulExit(signal_number, frame):
        print('Signal received....Exiting gracefully')
        sys.exit(0)

def main():
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, gracefulExit)
```

```
parser = ap.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--latency', help='Latency in ms')
parser.add_argument('--mbxip', help='MBX IP')
parser.add_argument('--addLatency', help='Add latency on interface', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--removeLatency', help='Remove latency from interface', action='store_true')

elif args.addLatency:
        add_latency(args.mbxip, args.latency)
        if signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, gracefulExit):
                remove_latency(args.mbxip, args.latency)
elif args.removeLatency:
        remove_latency(args.mbxip, args.latency)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
                main()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                pass
```

I am not able to invoke a SIGINT and remove latency. What is happening is the latency is added and removed right away and the script is exited. I am running the script as **./script.py --addLatency --latency 25 --mbxip**

What I want is once I have added the latency, the script would exit when SIGINT is invoked with control + c and would remove the latency before exiting. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use signals. You have to remove the latency in the except block which is executed when ctrl-c is pressed.

But after you add the latency the program will reach the end and exit. You should somehow pause the execution in the try block, for example with `input()` or `sleep(99999999)`

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, it works with what you have suggested.